# Compile error on begin() method of a class

Tags: c++

Tried to create a class to keep track of packets within the last 2 seconds, but got compile error.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
g++ -std=c++11 map2.cc 
map2.cc:20:2: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::iterator’ without an argument list
  iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
```

Here is the little class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
class cEvents {
public:
    list<pair<double, int>> l;
    int add(double ts, int pktNum, double maxTime) {
        l.push_back(make_pair(ts, pktNum));
        pair<double, int> tmp;
        while (1) {
            tmp = l.front();
            if ((ts - tmp.first) < maxTime) break;
            l.pop_front();
        }
        return l.size();
    }
    iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
};

int main () {
    cEvents e;
    cout << e.add(0, 1, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(0.1,2, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(0.2,3, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(0.5,4, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(1.2,5, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(1.7,6, 2) << endl;
    for (auto x : e) {
        //cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    }
    cout << e.add(2.2,7, 2) << endl;
    cout << e.add(3.2,8, 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convenient solution: Change the return type of begin() to auto

Comment: `using namespace std;` contributes to the confusion here; that's why the compiler thinks that `iterator` refers to `std::iterator`. And that's why `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Comment: @MetalMessiah, would be nice to have `auto` here, but I got warning `map2.cc:20:13: warning: ‘begin’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
  auto begin() { return l.begin(); }` when I change it to `auto begin() { return l.begin(); }`

Comment: Thanks @pete-becker for the caution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the return type to what you want to return.

Try this: `list<pair<double, int>>::iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }`

**UPDATE:** the compiler told me that you have to create `end()` function as a member of `class cEvents`. It should be like this:

```
list<pair<double, int>>::iterator end() { return l.end(); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It works! SO prevents me from accepting it right now. Will do it later today.

Comment: It works, but (IMO) it's still the wrong way to go about fixing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the iterator of the container as the return type.

```
iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
```

Should be

```
list<pair<double, int>>::iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
```

Or in C++14

```
auto begin() { return l.begin(); }
```

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, your solution is good too. I like c++14 but it's not available on my g++ (4.8.4) yet.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `begin()` to return some type named `iterator`, but you haven't defined what type that actually is.

The only type the compiler can find by that name is `std::iterator`, which is a class template, so you can't use it without a template parameter list (and it's probably not what you want in this case anyway).

In this case, it looks to me like you probably want your `begin()` (and `end()`) to return iterators into the `list<pair<double, int>>` that the object contains, so you'd do something like:

```
typedef list<pair<double, int>>::iterator iterator;
```

...or, better still:

```
typedef decltype(l)::iterator iterator;
```

...or equivalently (but more readably, at least in some people's view):

```
using iterator = decltype(l)::iterator;
```

Then, since you've defined what `iterator` means, you can use the name as the return type of your function (or as a parameter, etc.) Given that you apparently have something that acts/works like a collection anyway, you'd probably be better off defining the other "standard" types for a collection as well (e.g., `typedef std::pair<double, int> value_type;` as well.

I would advise *against* directly specifying `std::list<std::pair<double, int>>::iterator` as the return type. This does work, but it contains substantial redundancy. You always want that return type to be the same as the iterator type for the collection, so if you change your mind and use some other collection instead of `list`, the return type of the function needs to change to match. Using `decltype(l)::iterator` makes that automatic, where using `std::list<std::pair<double, int>>::iterator` requires that you do manual editing to keep the types in sync.

I should probably add that in this particular case, I think making it easy to change to a different type as easily as possible is more important than usual. Specifically, using `std::list` is a mistake *much* more often than not, so unless this is throwaway code, chances of wanting to change to a different container are quite high.

Comment: Thanks @jerry-coffin for the detailed answer.  Really like your suggestion of using `decltype(l)::iterator` which looks simpler and more robust.